# Hibernate: alter table User_Address drop foreign key FK_im39k3og2pvx7vvqdcy35s0g0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

when i ran my code at first it worked correctly but later i am unable access those 
tables?

Here is my code:-

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/navlic</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>


         <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
         <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>          

        <mapping class="dto.UserDetails"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Main class:-

```
package dto;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails ud=new UserDetails();
        ud.setUserName("Second user");


        Address homead=new Address();
        homead.setCity("smg");
        homead.setCountry("aa");
        homead.setHouse("bb");
        homead.setStreet("cc");
        homead.setState("dd");


        Address officead=new Address();
        officead.setCity("smg");
        officead.setCountry("ee");
        officead.setHouse("ff");
        officead.setStreet("gg");
        officead.setState("hh");


        ud.getAddr().add(homead);
        ud.getAddr().add(officead);


            SessionFactory sf;
            ServiceRegistry sr;
            Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure();
            sr=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).build();
            sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory(sr);


        Session s=sf.openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(ud);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();

        ud=null;
        s=sf.openSession();
        //if type is lazy it returns only the variables of that class no more reference variables.
        //if type is Eager it returns all the elements of user class
        ud=(UserDetails)s.get(UserDetails.class, 1);
        System.out.println(ud.getAddr().size());


    }

}
```

Model class:-

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int UserId;
    private String UserName;



    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="User_Address",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="User_Id"))
    @GenericGenerator(name="hilo-gen" ,strategy="hilo")
    @CollectionId(columns={@Column(name="AddressId")},generator="hilo-gen",type=@Type(type="long"))
    private Collection<Address> addr=new ArrayList<Address>();


    public Collection<Address> getAddr() {
        return addr;
    }
    public void setAddr(Collection<Address> addr) {
        this.addr = addr;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

}
```

Address class is here :-

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    @Column(name="Office_name")
    private String House;
    public String getHouse() {
        return House;
    }
    public void setHouse(String house) {
        House = house;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return Street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        Street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }
    @Column(name="street_name")
    private String Street;
    @Column(name="city_name")
    private String City;
    @Column(name="state_name")
    private String State;
    @Column(name="country_name")
    private String Country;


}
```

when i try to run my code there is no error from hibernate but an mysql error is encountered I am new to mysql can anyone explain me in deatil the cause of this error and how to fix it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it seems a mysql foreign key related issue but more information will be required to identify the issue, so what ever sql statement you are executing by your code just execute directly either by any gui like sqlyog or server console..and check error..

Comment: you can also check if whatever user's address you are trying to insert/update/delete in user_address table exists in its master table may be users...

Comment: I am unable to open those particular table where i am doing these wrks The Mysql is not responding only for those tables

Comment: you are able to check table definition you can use command - "desc table_name;"....if getting any error then share...

Comment: either select DB then execute this command or try "desc dbname.tablename" OR "use dbname; desc tablename;" and then check.

Comment: the desc is working but select queries are  not wrking

Comment: It seems your table is myisam, if yes then use "repair table tablename" and then try...

Comment: when i run select query the mysql never executes it , it keeps on loading.

Comment: before executing select query are u selecting db, please execute "use mydb;" command first and then execute your select statement.

Comment: sry i could not get u can u explain me in detail

Comment: try as per following "use mydb; select * from mytable limit 1;" mytable here is in which table you are getting issue and check are you getting output.

Comment: SELECT * FROM navlic.user_address; this the query i am executing which never executes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88179/discussion-between-srikanth-r-and-zafar-malik).